# set a variable of int into a variable of [NSNumber : Int]

Tags: ios, swift2, slrequest

I am having trouble of using the parameters in SLRequest for Twitter (as it must be a type of [NSObject : AnyObject]!, yet the Twitter API requested Int as parameters). What I do is leaving the parameter constant as [NSObject : AnyObject] and planning to declare another variable to change it to Integer. How to achieve this?

```
var userName : String!
var text : String!
var name : String!
var tweetID : [NSObject : AnyObject]!
var twtID : Int!

tweetID = twtID as [NSObject : AnyObject]

var userLocation : String!
var UserImgURLStr: String?

init(jsonDataDictiony : [String : AnyObject])
{

    self.text = jsonDataDictiony["text"] as! String
    self.twtID = jsonDataDictiony["id"] as! Int!
```

the declaration of tweetID = twtID as [NSObject : AnyObject] gives error

Or is it possible to replace the whole variable type and use Integer in the parameters?

edit 2: I have decided to change the type (after reinspecting, [NSObject : AnyObject] is only the expected argument type) into [NSNumber : Int], any idea how to hook up the int value found from the Twitter API into the variable TweetID?

```
var userName : String!
var text : String!
var name : String!
var tweetID : [NSNumber : Int]!
var tweetIDInt : Int!

var userLocation : String!
var UserImgURLStr: String?

init(jsonDataDictiony : [String : AnyObject])
{

    self.text = jsonDataDictiony["text"] as! String
    self.tweetIDInt = jsonDataDictiony["id"] as! Int
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration of `tweetID = twtID as [NSObject : AnyObject]` causes two errors.

- You cannot cast an `Int` to a dictionary (`[NSObject : AnyObject]`).
- You cannot execute code like this line on the top level of the class.

Assign the value for the appropriate key in a method

```
tweetID["id"] = twtID
```

Since both `text` and `twtID` seem to exist all the time and are initialized in the `init` method declare them as non-optional.

Comment: See the second reason: You have to put the code into a method.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am still new in Swift and even though your code works well, it shows up nil in the tweetID and thus breaking the process. I reverted the whole code to only using tweetID as Int. I will edit my question to the newer part of my app in which the error initially exists.

Comment: The reason of your edited question is reason 1: **You cannot cast (and assign) an `Int` to a dictionary** because the types are different.

Comment: Yes I realise that @vadian , but what can I do to overcome this?

Comment: Your code does not show where and how `twtID` is used so nobody (except you) can know what the variable is supposed to do.

Comment: I use twtID solely for converting id from Int (the API requirement) into NSObjects : AnyObjects (SLRequest.parameter requirement). If its redundant, can you show me how to do it? @vadian

Comment: `id` is an `Int` and a dictionary is a collection type containing key/value pairs. I wrote in my answer how to set a value (`twtID`) in a dictionary for a specific key (`"id"`).

Comment: Hey @vadian, I have edited my question (and also my code), would you please check on this?

Comment: What's that `[NSNumber : Int]!` for? It's also a dictionary and it's not used in the edited code. Please read the chapter about collection types in the Swift Language Guide to understand the function of a dictionary. PS: Meanwhile the question is confusing because of all the editing.

Comment: Yes I never added the part of why I am using NSNumber instead of Integer blindly (its in a different class), as it would be a very wild code and I am not sure of how to share it properly @vadian